# Why Collections like HashMap / table check hashcode() for add/put and check equals() for contains()

Tags: java, hashcode

I don't understand why Map.put() checks only hashcode() and Map.containsKey() checks only equals().

Why not maintain consistency . Either check hashcode in both case or equals in both case.

Comment: As the answer below points out, a hash-code is guaranteed to be unique for anyone object however, it is guaranteed to be the same for all similar inputs ( or else it wouldn't work for lookups). This is how things like collisions happen. Also note that a hash in general is a one-way transfer. I.e. the output tells you nothing about the input. Encryption is a two-way transfer.

Comment: `Map.put()` doesn't check anything - it's a method signature of an interface. `HashMap.put()` checks hashCode due to its implementation, but `TreeMap` does not. Also, all implementations of Map check `equals()` in `put()`, even HashMap - they must to obey the contract.

Comment: Map.put () checks the hashcode() , I tried doing that by overriding hashcode() and putting a print statement inside it.

Comment: @DavidPrun that depends on the `Map` implementation. `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` uses `hashCode` and `equals`, while `TreeMap` doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Two or more objects could return the same `hashCode` but they can be only the same if they are `equals`.

[`Map#containsKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) only explains that the implementation should use `equals` method to compare keys. But this doesn't mean implementations cannot use `hashCode` to search for the keys that *may* be the desired key. This is noted in `HashMap#containsKey` implementation. Posting the implementation of the method from Java 8's sources:

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return getNode(hash(key), key) != null;
}

static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}

final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
            do {
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    return e;
            } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that `TreeMap` doesn't work with `hashCode`s, instead uses natural comparison of the keys. So, there's no need to use `hashCode` in this implementation. Note that [`TreeMap#containsKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) changes the javadoc to explain it doesn't uses `equals` method. Showing the source code of this method from Java 8's sources, which doesn't use `equals` at all (comments are mine):

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return getEntry(key) != null;
}

final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    // Offload comparator-based version for sake of performance
    if (comparator != null)
        return getEntryUsingComparator(key);
    if (key == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
    Entry<K,V> p = root;
    //navigating through the nodes of the inner red black tree
    while (p != null) {
        //using result of compareTo method to check if the key is found
        //this replaces usage of equals method
        int cmp = k.compareTo(p.key);
        if (cmp < 0)
            p = p.left;
        else if (cmp > 0)
            p = p.right;
        else
            return p;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the relationship between `hashCode()` and `equals()`. If two objects are equal, they must have the same hash code, but *the reverse is not necessarily true*.

Thus, if you want to see if a collection contains something, you *cannot* use `hashCode()` for equality checks, otherwise if you happen to have two unequal objects that return the same number for `hashCode()`, you start to run into major problems.

In addition, `hashCode()` is more intended to *complement* `equals()`, and is primarily intended for hash collections, due to the way hash tables work. From the javadoc for [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

> `public int hashCode()`
>
> Returns a hash code value for the object. This method is supported for the benefit of hash tables such as those provided by HashMap.

Hash tables work by calculating a "hash" for an object, which, after some math, provides an index into a backing array. Given a good `hashCode()` implementation, this allows for a collection with amortized O(1) `put()`, `get()`, `contains()`, and other methods, which is a highly desirable property.

However, this is mainly just a convenience feature. In the end, the map must *still* use `equals()` to ensure that the object you're retrieving is actually the one you want. It is possible, in fact, to write `Map` implementations that don't use `hashCode()` at all, such as `TreeSet`, which uses `compareTo()`.

Comment: then it still makes sense checking only equals in both cases right?

Comment: Not really; I'm expanding my answer. Give me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

We can't use contains() for add() because, when we want to find the location/address to store an element, we use the hashcode() and insert it. However, when checking if key already exists, using contains(), it is necessary to compare existing element with sample key using equals method.

Now I get it. Thanks all.

Comment: You got it wrong. In fact, both `HashMap` and `TreeMap` doesn't call `contains` method directly but use a similar code to check if the key-value pair already exists in the map.